# How to remove some highlighted words of text area on form submit

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have used jQuery to highlight some text. Is it possible to remove these words from `textarea` .

```
<textarea cols="50" rows="5">...</textarea>

<script>
  $('textarea').highlightTextarea({
  color: '#ADF0FF',
    words: ['Lorem ipsum', 'vulputate'],
  resizable: true
  });
</script>
```

Comment: anything is possible, what have you tried? what does your controller code look like?

Comment: i am trying hard.. just want to del these words on submit..have't made a controler .. wordking in plain html,js only right now..

Comment: I [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48919053/2) your post - why did you go undo it for?

Comment: Does the form submit to the same page, or another page? Is it a GET or a POST?

Comment: i need some formating help.. i don't know how to write in code blocks..

Comment: @SpyderScript its POST

Comment: Can you please edit your post and show us the code you tried *even if it isn't working)... as well as telling us the error you saw?

Answer (score 1):

Before submit your form you can get textarea value and replace your word with blank using loop like this.

```js
var  words = ['Lorem ipsum', 'vulputate'];
var result=$('#txtContain').text();
$.each( words, function( index, value ){
  result = result.replace(value,'');
  
});
console.log(result.trim());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea cols="50" rows="5" id='txtContain'>Lorem ipsum is vulputate simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </textarea>
```